# Help with proof of boundedness of the union of bounded sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am trying to prove that the union of a finite number of bounded sets is bounded. A set $A$ is bounded if diameter, $d(A)$ is finite, and $d(A)=\sup_{x,y\in A}\rho(x,y)$ where $\rho(.)$ is metric.

My idea is to use induction. So, let $n=2$ and $A_1$ & $A_2$ be both bounded sets. Take $x,y\in A$ where $A=A_1\cup A_2$. In particular $x\in A_1$ and $y\in A_2$ Wlog $A_1\cap A_2=\emptyset$, otherwise consider $A_1\cup(A_2-A_1)$.
$$
\rho(x,y)\leq\rho(x,x_1)+\rho(x_1,y_1)+\rho(y_1,y)\leq d(A_1)+\rho(x_1,y_1)+d(A_2)
$$
where $x_1\in A_1, y_1\in A_2$. I can't find a way to show $\rho(x_1,y_1)$ is finite i.e., the distance between a point of $A_1$ and a point of $A_2$ is finite. Many thanks for any help!

Comment: That's part of the definition of a metric. The distance between any two points is finite.

Comment: I have never seen this before. I only know 3 properties, namely non-negativity, symmetry and triangle inequality.Can you lead me where to find this info?

Comment: metric is a function $d:X\times X\to\Bbb R_{\ge0}=[0,\infty)$. But there should also be a fourth property, namely $d(x,y)=0\iff x=y$.

Comment: A metric is a function $d \colon X\times X \to \mathbb{R}$. It takes only finite values.

Comment: The definition of distance is $\rho:X\times X\to \Bbb R_+$. Hence for any two given points $a$ and $b$ the distance $\rho (a,b)$ is always finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually done because you managed to bound $\rho(x,y)$ by something independent of $x$ and $y$. You cannot avoid the $x_1$ and $y_1$ because the diameter of the union depends on the gap between the sets.

Notice that there is no need to assume $A$ and $B$ disjoint.